# Swift: (lldb) Thread 1: signal SIGABRT ERROR

Tags: ios

When I start my app I get `(lldb) Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error`.

What can I do to fix this?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the [ask] help page to learn how to ask good questions. You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on topic.

Comment: https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devda5478599 You need to read/tell us what's happening in Console (bottom right) and if a specific line is causing the issue. Else, we can't guess. Maybe because of file 5 (in alphabetic number) line 18 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is probably a duplicate and has been answered before; https://stackoverflow.com/a/8087739

Check you IBOutlet properties to see if there a no bad connections.

Comment: Thank you! This worked! It was an bad connection from an label to my code